# LosFormatter Deserialisation error "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting weird error while Deserialisation of simple string. I don't know what exactly I'm doing wrong.

```
LosFormatter Formatter = new LosFormatter();
result = Formatter.Deserialize("Dashboard");
```

> Error : System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char
>   array or string.

Please help me.

Comment: actually the function is made for byte data and I was passing plain string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you mean to *serialize*? Serialization turns any object into a certain data format, in this case, a base64 string, and deserialization is the exact opposite. You can only deserialize stuff that your formatter previously created with serialization, in this case, deserialization expects a base64 string, but you didn't give it one. It's almost never the other way around.

Comment: Thanks actually the function is made for byte data and I was passing plain string.